# Akka HTTP + Scala: internationalization

Tags: scala, internationalization, akka-http

What is the best way to implement localization support on Akka-HTTP with Scala?

I considered the following libraries:

- [scala-i18n](https://github.com/osinka/scala-i18n)
- [Play Framework ScalaI18N](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaI18N)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, it practically not advisable to implement such thing on Akka HTTP even if possible. Localization implementation is ideal for Web frameworks. You should consider using Play Framework with the libraries earlier suggested.